# Что не так я сделал?Вылезает ошибка x<y<z не имеют своего математического значения

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i;
  const double a = 0.3;
  cout << " Меню " << endl;
  cout << " Ввести номер задачі 1 - 2 " << endl;
  cin >> i;
  switch (i) 
  {
  case 1: {
    double x, y;
    cout << " Введіть х " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x < 3)
    {
      y = log(x) + exp(x);
    }
    else
      if (3 <= x <= 6);
    {
      y = 2 * a * sin(x) + pow(a, 2);
    }
      else
        if (x > 6);
    {
      y = (a * x + 3) / sqrt(x - 1);
    }
    cout << "y=" << y << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: `3 <= x <= 6` => `3 <= x && x <= 6`

Comment: А лучше `x <= 6`, потому что на `x < 3` вы его уже проверили выше)